# jinja - how to check if one input value is smaller than the other?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a flesk registration form, and I request the user to input two numbers, one of which has to be smaller than the other. I see how I can read the values into the python app and confirm that they are correct, but I would like to have it check as the user type them. Is this possible, or should I brash the dust of my poor JS skills?

I thought that it might look like

```
<input type='number' name='foo' value='1'></input>
<input type='number' name='bar' value='2' min={{ request.foo.value + 1 }}></input>
```

but I get an error message `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'flask.wrappers.Request object' has no attribute 'foo'`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying force "bar" to always be grater than "foo" here is a code example you can use.

```js
// get the input elements
let foo = document.querySelector('[name="foo"]');
let bar = document.querySelector('[name="bar"]')

// set initial min attribute for bar to be grater than foo
bar.setAttribute('min', +foo.value + 1);

// update the min attribute of bar everytime foo changes
foo.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
 bar.setAttribute('min', +foo.value + 1)
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input required type="number" name="foo" value="1" />
  <input required type="number" name="bar" value="" />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```